# sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit does not produce splits as how it supposed to produce

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So, I need to produce test/train/validation splits with predefined groups. I don't want to use LeavePGroupsOut since I need to separate data according my desired percantages into training and validation sets. In the documentation of GroupShuffleSplit, for `test_size` parameter, it's said that:

> test_size : float, int, None, optional
>   If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split. **If int, represents the absolute number of test samples**. If None, the value is set to the complement of the train size. By default, the value is set to 0.2. The default will change in version 0.21. It will remain 0.2 only if train_size is unspecified, otherwise it will complement the specified train_size.

However, this is indeed not the case as in the following code:

```
tr, ts = next(GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=3).split(TR_set, groups=tr_groups))
print(tr)
print(ts)
```

which prints out for instance:

`[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73
  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  91  92  93
  99 101 102 103 104 105 106 107]
[ 26  27  89  90  94  95  96  97  98 100]`

As you see above, test size is not 3 but more than 3. This almost always the case. I checked the groups of the indices. Apparently, if test_size is an integer, it represents the absolute number of test groups, **not samples**. I think the documentation is misleading.

Also, when test_size is a float, it mostly does not consider the ratio specified. It may be due to unequal sample sizes in the groups but then there must be a note/warning to specify what kind of behaviour it follows under unequal group sizes combined with test_size ratio.

```
tr, ts = next(GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.1).split(TR_set, groups=tr_groups))
print(len(tr))
print(len(ts))
```

which gives:

```
70
38
```

where test size is 35% of the whole set (it supposed to be 10%).

So, either I'm missing something or the documentation is nothing but erroneous decriptions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bugs but the documentation was not correct at some points. I opened an issue in the [scikit-learn's github page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13369) for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on GroupShuffleSplit documentation:

> Note: The parameters test_size and train_size refer to groups, and not
> to samples, as in ShuffleSplit.

So, test_size is expected to be number of groups, which is what you found in the results too.

Comment: Doc is updated, see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13369